# Implement reference field search feature using GAE/webapp2/Jinja2

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2, webapp2, app-engine-ndb

I'm writing a web application using GoogleAppEngine (GAE), webapp2, Jinja2 and Twitter Bootstrap.
I do want to manage objects which may have a location through a web interface.

I've got the following location model (models/location.py):

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Location(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty(required=False)
    address = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
    latitude = ndb.FloatProperty(required=False)
    longitude = ndb.FloatProperty(required=False)
```

I've also got a basic object model (models/object.py):

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import polymodel
from location import Location

class Object(polymodel.PolyModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty(required=False)
    location = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Location, required=False)
    position = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
```

I did create a html template (templates/object-create.html) to create new objects. So far the input field for "location" looks as following:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputLocation">Location</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="location" id="inputLocation" placeholder="Location">
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I make the input field searchable? I would like to write the location name or address.
Am I missing a technology here? Is this where WTForms would come in place?

-Luca.

Comment: What do you mean by 'searchable'? Have it suggest values from those that already exist as you type?

Comment: Yes, as I type I would like to retrieve a list of matching entries. But it should search in more than 1 field. For example in Location.name OR Location.address.

Comment: I did do more research. I think it has to be a combination of jquery's typeahead (frontend) and google's search API (backend).